# HttpClient 4.x: how to retain cookies across multiple requests?

Tags: authentication, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to use Apache HttpClient (4.x) to make 3 consecutive web calls and essentially log me into my app programmatically:

1. An HTTP GET to a login page (`http://myapp01.example.com`)
2. The server will respond to this GET with a response cookie "`JSESSIONID`"
3. An HTTP POST to the same page (using the same `JSESSIONID` as a request cookie)
4. The server now authenticates me and validates the `JSESSIONID`.
5. An HTTP GET to a different page under the same domain (`http://myapp01.example.com/fizz`), again using the same `JSESSIONID` as a request cookie

The first GET's response will contain a cookie named `JSESSIONID`. The POST will then log me in to the server (sending username and password data in the POST request body). This POST will also send (`Set-Cookie`) the `JSESSIONID` cookie received from the first GET. If my logins are successful, the `JSESSIONID` will now be authenticated, and I am logged in. I can then make the 2nd GET call (still using the same `JSESSIONID`) to `/fizz` which is ordinarily an authenticated URL.

Can this be done in HttpClient 4? I see there is a method `HttpClient.getCookieStore()`. but this seems to only store cookies per GET/POST/PUT/etc.

**Any ideas as to how I can get this holding cookies across multiple requests, such that any cookies returned by the server are then added to subsequent requests?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache HttpClient takes care of that automatically (since version 2)

Comment: Thanks @oleg (+1) - so the `HttpClient.getCookieStore()` will keep an aggregating list of cookies in between multiple web calls?

Comment: Yes, _provided_ they share the same context / cookie store

Comment: Thanks again @oleg (+1) - so are cookie stores context-specific? Basically, I need to GET `http://myapp01/login`, then POST the same URL, then GET `http://myapp01/fizzbuzz`. So will this work, or will HttpClient see `/login` and `/fizzbuzz` as 2 different contexts, and therefore place their cookies in 2 different stores?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a servlet or webapp context. It is up the client side code to treat a sequence of logically related requests as one session by making them share HttpContext as described here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e223

Comment: Thanks again @oleg (+1) - so how do I go about ensuring that my requests use the same HTTP context? Are you saying that my user case is already covered by this, or do I have to incorporate the "Context API" documented on the link you provided? Thanks again!

Comment: If you do nothing and execute requests without an explicit context HttpClient will create an HttpContext instance automatically and will pre-populate it with default values such as the default cookie store and so on. This way requests will end up sharing cookies of the default cookie store. I would however still recommend to use an explicit context for logically related requests.